# how to re-initialize alsa audio to load new asound.conf file

Tags: sound, bluetooth, alsa, playback

I am having a music player application which is able to play music through on board audio jack and Bluetooth headset with different asound.conf configuration.

I need the same application take different asound.conf file when i need to change the playback device.

In fact how do i change the audio playback device from my c application itlself. ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `asound.conf` file is read by the ALSA library when you open some device for the first time.

In your own application, you can call [snd_config_update()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___config.html#ga41a3d2202cfb9016e33aa85ea70a4c9c) to re-read the configuration files.

If you want to affect some other application that you have no control over, you have to restart it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, snd_config_update() is not actually doing what i have expected. But i have got some other configurations updated and went useful in other ways.

i am using snd_pcm_open() with my device name as one of the arguement. if in case one device fails i am calling the same function again with the other playback device and its working.